# Use of Java module java.smartcardio

Tags: java, module

I have trouble to use the module java.smartcardio. In my understanding I just just create a module-info.java and add

```
module apdu {
  requires java.smartcardio;
}
```

I placed this file directly in the package. But this does not resolve my ``... cannot be resolved to a type`. Also

```
module com.test.bla.xxx.apdu {
  requires java.smartcardio;
}
```

did not work.

Am I missing a setup step or something? Before now we did not use the module system yet.

Comment: Hi, could you explain a bit more in detail how your project is structured and what exactly your issue is?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and sorry for the unspecific question. I am no architect and modules are new to me. I have imported some code which uses the javax.smartcardio package. I get errors "xxx cannot be resolved to a type". Since the module is part of Java11 - which we use - I would like to figure out how to use it. By the way, I am using Eclipse and Gradle. What more information do you need?

Comment: The project is really old and started before the introduction of Java 9/modules. So I guess I am missing a step here.

Comment: Well, the module system is optional. It is meant for big projects to make dependencies between multiple modules and external modules more visible. You should be able to use any smartdcardio package without a module description.

Just import the classes as usual.